# PHP MYSQL calculate years and days

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how i can calculate my age and remaining days with MySQL, taking into account of leap years?

I found examples which can calculate the total number of days.

But i want a result like:

```
22 years, 134 days,
23 years, 361 days    
24 years, 11 days
```

For now i got this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  dob,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dob, now() ) as _year,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, dob, now() ) % 12 as _month,
  FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, dob, now() ) % 30.4375 ) as _day
FROM 
  client
```

But this doesn't work and % 30.4375 is not a solution for leap years.

Comment: What You Tried? Where You Faced Problem? Please Paste Your Tried Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```
SELECT 
  name,
  dob,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, now()) years, 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, now()), dob), now()) days
FROM
   client;
```

First part gets the years, second part adds years to date of birth to get last birthday & then gets number of days since then.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a primarily a database and not and render engine. I would suggest using the PHP DateTime Object to handle the timespan - after loading the data from the MySQL server:

```
$d1=new DateTime($row['dob']);
$d2=new DateTime('now');
$diff=$d2->diff($d1);
print_r( $diff ) ;
```